# django: почему нет ссылок?

Tags: python, django, views, django-urls, reverse

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import about_s,menu
urlpatterns = [
    path('', menu),
    path('<str:week>/', about_s, name='reverse'),

]
```

**ЭТО URLconf**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import *
from django.urls import reverse
WEEK={ 'monday':'понедельник', 'tuesday':'вторник',  'wednesday':'среда',
       'thursday':'четверг',  'friday':'пятница',  'saturday':'суббота',
       'sunday':'воскресенье'
       }
def menu(request):
    week_list = list(WEEK)
    li_elements = ''
    for i in week_list:
        url = reverse('reverse', args=(i,))
        li_elements += f"<li> <a href='{url}' {i} </a> </li>"

    result =f"""<ol>{li_elements}</ol>"""
    return HttpResponse(result)

def about_s(request, week:str):
    info = WEEK.get(week)

    if info:
        return HttpResponse(f'{info}')
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('str ')
```

**ЭТО views**

ВОПРОС: ПОЧЕМУ нет ссылок?
[image]

Comment: У вас некорректный html-код. Посмотрите исходный код этой страницы, и, возможно, в нём вы поймёте свою ошибку

Comment: Спасибо. li_elements += f"<li><a href='{url}'>{i}</a></li>"